# Break line between two TextView's - XML

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to application developing, and I've faced a problem with separating between two TextView's.
My Code:

```
   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.90"
            android:text="@string/addone"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDisplay2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.90"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
```

How do I manage to make them in two different horizontal lines?

Comment: Use Linear Layout or table row as parent.

Comment: Tried that, won't work.

Comment: exactly what you want? Put some image. That would help to understand your requirements better

Comment: Please post complete `xml` code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:text="@string/addone"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add This to your LinearLayout:

```
   android:orientation="vertical"
```